# Visual studio automatically change my resource string to plain text

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I set resource string to text property on my controls, but when I move something on form, or add any controls, resources are changing to plain text.

Here are images,

[before moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue8v7.png)

```
this.button1.Text = Resources.Foo;
this.label1.Text = Resources.Foo;
```

[after moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut1oF.png)

```
this.button1.Text = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.Foo;
this.label1.Text = "Sample text";
```

I want to effect like on button.

Comment: Please copy/paste the code instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: You are manually modifying `.designer.cs` file. You shouldn't be doing that because it's auto generated after any change in the designer.

Comment: As Ivan said, unless you really know what you are doing, don't touch or worry about the `.designer.cs` file.